# How To Call Dynamic Model in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

How to call dynamic Model in Laravel 4 ?

Imagine that I have this

```
$job = CfgJob::orderBy('Name')->get();
```

What I want to do is to pass value to call the model. Something like this

```
$value='Job';

$job = Cfg.$value::orderBy('Name')->get();
```

Is it possible to this on PHP and Laravel 4 ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121559/2539605

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a static method on a variable class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642391/how-can-i-call-a-static-method-on-a-variable-class)

Comment: if o do this 

    $classname = 'CfgDirector';
    $dir=$classname::orderBy('Name')->get();

It says class not found.

To solve i need to specify the path of model

    $dir="Director";
    $classname = 'app\models\Cfg'.$dir;
    $dir=$classname::orderBy('Name')->get();

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work (cant test it at the moment):

```
$value='Job';
$value= ('Cfg'.$value);

$job = $value::orderBy('Name')->get();
```