# PHP call a static method of a class by class name

Tags: php

This is a syntax question I think... I have an array of classnames, that I use in a factory to generate objects by object type code:

```
$array = ['a' => '\namespace\AClass', 'b' => '\namespace\BClass'];
```

I can instantiate these classes from the string name just fine:

```
$classname = $array['a'];
return new $classname($arg1, $arg2);
```

What I am trying to do is call a static method of the class named in the array or string, without having to initialize the object - something like:

```
$classname = $array['a'];
return $classname::formatArg($arg1);
```

Obviously, this doesn't work since $classname is a string, so how do I tell PHP I am trying to access the object with that name?

Comment: Are you sure this doesnt work? If so, you can use call_user_func. It works with class methods, no matter if instance or static.

Comment: What error are you getting? I ran a simple version of this and it works. `class AClass {
 static function formatArg($arg1) { echo $arg1; }
}
$array = array('a' => '\AClass', 'b' => '\namespace\BClass');
$arg1 = 'hello';
$classname = $array['a'];
var_dump($classname);
$classname::formatArg($arg1);`

Comment: Huh. I tried it again and it is in fact working. I was getting an unexpected character error in PHP before (maybe a typo?) and the IDE flagged it as an error "Method formatArg not found in string" Thanks for the replies and testing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post. [How can I call a static method on a variable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642391/how-can-i-call-a-static-method-on-a-variable-class)

It look like your code is ok in php 5.3. There's also some ideas how to deal with your problem if you are < 5.3.