# Laravel Eloquent Find Not Working When Given String Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have A Model In Laravel stored in variable as String.

```
$model = "App\Models\City";
```

What I want is

```
$model::find(1) to fetch the City with ID of 1
```

But It's not working as it is expected. However, when I do

```
City::find(1)
```

Not using the $model variable. I can fetch my expected result.

Anyone?

Comment: is you primary key called `id` or something else

Comment: @linktoahref I also did that but it only returns null.

Comment: [From the string name of a class, can I get a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354628/6521116)

Comment: @usrNotFound I already set $primaryKey in my model to update my primary Key

Comment: `$model = "App\Models\City";`  need to be `$model = "App\Models\Country";`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Updated

Comment: have you tried with `call_user_func()`, like `call_user_func(array($model , 'find'));` not sure just curious.

Comment: Can you show us your error?

Comment: `$model = use City; $model::find(1);`  check this

Comment: `$model = app("App\Models\City"); $model::find(1); //returns null if there isn't a record`

Answer (score 5):

You could resolve the class out of [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container)

```
$model = app("App\Models\City");
$model::find(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this, you  can refer [How can I call a static method on a variable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/642391/6521116) for more.

```
$city = call_user_func($class . '::find', 1);
```

Comment: This will give error you need to remove Scope Resolution Operator (::)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func)

Try this:

```
$model = "App\Models\City";
$id =1
$city = call_user_func(array($model, 'find'), $id);
```

Comment: how is it different then @Krish Roofe answer. Oh! i see you have parameter for value